# Неполный условный оператор Java

Tags: java, if

Прошу объяснить, а лучше дать пример, чем полный условный оператор отличается от неполного. Я это представляю так :
Полный:

```
if(){} else{}
```

Неполный:

```
if(){}
```

Правильно?

Comment: А `if () {} else if () {} else {}` тогда полнее полного получается.

Comment: Да. Полный условный оператор определяет преемника как при истинности, так и ложности логического выражения.

Comment: @Sergey if() else if () считается не полным? Вопрос в чем, дали ДЗ, написано : дано 2 числа, определить большее число при помощи 1 не полного условного оператора.

Comment: @aleks.andr так получается if else это не полный?

Comment: `if() else if ()` это неполный вложенный в полный

Comment: @4per Вопрос в чем, дали ДЗ, написано : дано 2 числа, определить большее число при помощи 1 не полного условного оператора. Это же нельзя решить одним условным if() правильно, так как он возвращает true\false. Правильно?

Comment: @Winteriscoming Можно решить. Например, что-нибудь в этом духе: `max = a; if (a < b) { max = b };`

Comment: @Yaant а если равны?

Comment: @4per В задании сказано только про поиск большего)

Comment: @Denis большее и максимальное -- разные понятия на мой вкус

Comment: короч. да, полный `if/else`, неполный - только `if`

Comment: @4per тогда это будет undefined behavior, ибо в условии задачи подобная ситуация никак не обговорена. И волевым решением можно вернуть `a`. :)

Answer (score 1):

Наверное, просили написать метод:

```
public int f(int a, int b) {
    if (a > b) {
        return a;
    }
    return b;
}
```

Тогда мы используем 1 неполный условный оператор, и вернем наибольшее число, а если числа равны, то вернет любое из них.

Comment: не понятно, чем этот ответ хуже, ответа от @Yaant

Comment: @4per Наверное тем, что не является ответом на вопрос? Не раскрыта разница между полным и не полным if-ом, но вместо  этого выполнено тривиальное домашнее задание, которое к тому же всплыло в комментарии к основному вопросу. Вот кто-то очень строгий и заминусовал. Можете помочь несчастному действие обратным минусованию.

Comment: @Sergey на мой взгляд наличие домашнего задания в комментариях это проблема вопроса, а не ответа. Но ответом не является, согласен.

Comment: @4per вопрос остался вопросом, в коментах я просто раскрыл для чего задал вопрос. Подумал так будет понятней.